# How to open html page directly to div id location?

Tags: html

I am using tables to open 3 websites on one page - works fine.
I would like those pages to jump into a specific location when loaded but it does not seems to work.

I tried jumping to the div id location using:
https://example.com/home.html#div id

sometimes it works and sometimes not... what am I missing? Is this the best way to do it?

Please advice,

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? Are the pages in which it's failing long enough for that element to scroll to the top of the page?

Comment: I don't see it jump to the div location... it gives me the entire page (from top).

Comment: And the second question I asked, is the page long enough to scroll the linked element to the top of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an  tag as the first element in that div. And then navigating to https://example.com/home.html#blah will bring you there

Do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/w9sNc/6/

```
<a href="#blah">go to second div</a>
<div id="first"></div>

<div id="second">
   <a name="blah"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but can you provide more details?

Comment: You're downvoting me because I didn't provide enough details?

Comment: what? no, I appreciate your help. how can I fix that?